# Jumping across number line (Generalization of Putnam 2009 B2)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

An old Putnam problem is the following:

**Putnam 2009 B2**: A game involves jumping to the right on the real number line. If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers
and $b > a$, the cost of jumping from $a$ to $b$ is $$b^3-ab^2.$$ For what real numbers $c$ can one
travel from $0$ to $1$ in a finite number of jumps with total cost exactly $c$?

This is solved without too much difficulty by noticing that the total cost is a right Riemann sum of $f(x)=x^2,$ to get the answer of $$\left(\frac{1}{3},1\right].$$

If we change the problem slightly to make the cost of jumping $$(b-a)(b^2+a^2)$$ we can instead use trapezoidal approximations to the function $f(x)=2x^2$ to get a range of $$\left(\frac{2}{3},1\right].$$

**My (general) question is**: what happens when the cost is replaced with a different polynomial $$(b-a)p(a,b).$$ We can begin where $p$ is homogeneous, quadratic, and nonnegative on $[0,1]$.

In particular, I cannot solve the case where the cost is $$b^3-a^2b,$$ for example.